# Redirect URL for authorization code--design flaw in spec

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth

Friends, in the Authorization code flow, it states that after the /authorize call is initiated and success, the authorization code will be sent via HTTP 302 "redirect" URL to the client(say ReactJS webapp). Why the OAuth specification requires this to be sent in a redirect so the authorization code is sent in URL parameters exposed. I know it is recommended to use PKCE to handle this auth code leak issue, but my question is why OAuth spec requires us to send the auth code in 302 redirect in URL params in the 1st place. Why cannot the client(ReactJS webapp) place a simple GET request to the IDP and why cannot the IDP send back the auth code in the response body to the react JS application(say by xmlhttprequest). Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a OAuth2 service like Google, or some other service, and your react application would be able to handle the entire flow it means it can completely act on behalf of the user.

By requiring a redirect, it means that the user's own browser will go to the auth service's website, which is the only place the user can trust to safely enter their password and grant access to your application.

The URL in the addressbar means trust. Users are trained to never enter their password in a website they don't recognize.

Comment: Thanks Evert, your answer puts me on the right track now as i understand http 302 was intentional so the user can have a say and trust in the whole flow, thanks.